# use of unresolved identifier 'JSONEncoder' swift4

Tags: ios, swift, ubuntu, swift4

for example I just want to convert this sample array into a JSON object

```
var test = [String : Any] ()
test["title"] = "title"
test["description"] = "description"
test["date"] = Date.init()
```

and I get this error:

```
 use of unresolved identifier 'JSONEncoder'
print(JSONEncoder (test))
```

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`? Are you sure you're running Swift 4? What does "swift -version" output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the encoder correctly. Try this

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let json = try? encoder.encode(test)
```

Referencing app's document [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder), the only init method is like this, so you should not create the encoder itself to get you the JSON result.

> init()
>
> Creates a new, reusable JSON encoder with the default formatting
>   settings and encoding strategies.

Comment: Note that although this compiles (with Foundation imported), it will crash at runtime as `[String: Any]` is not `Encodable`.

Comment: I think I'm not importing something that I have to, for the "JSONEncoder", should I import something special?

Comment: @Amir It's under `Foundation` so you have to have that